# Azure Devops Wiki MarkDown Multiple Lines in Table

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, azure-devops-wiki

I'm trying to generate automation release notes in MD format and working as well but when I am trying to insert the content to Azure DevOps Wiki the whole table is broken.

Here is my syntax, which I first process as a Handlebars template:

```
| PullRequst ID | Commit Message | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
{{#forEach pullRequests}}
| [{{this.pullRequestId}}]| {{this.title}} |{{this.description}}|
{{/forEach}}
```

For PR-ID and Commit Message work as well, but for description can be multiple lines at the same time or full description of the commits.
Tried with `<br>` tag and with `<pre>` not working.

| PullRequst ID | Commit Message | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3183 | Last Commit Message | Fix commit message Second Message to be stored here |

How can I achieve this?
Thanks

Comment: Chris has updated his answer. Please check the answer if it can help you and we are willing to help you at any time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure DevOps Markdown [does support newlines in wiki tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#supported-in-markdown-widget--pull-requests--readme-files--wikis):

> To start a new line, use the HTML break tag (`<br/>`) (Works within a Wiki but not elsewhere)

Assuming you are really looking at a wiki and not something like a README, where newlines do *not* work in table cells, the problem is most likely that Handlebars is [escaping](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#html-escaping) your HTML `<br>` tag during pre-processing, turning it into something like `&lt;br&gt;`.

You can prevent this by using three braces instead of two for values that contain newlines, e.g.

```
{{{ this.description }}}
```

Note that this can be a security risk. I only recommend doing this if you have full control over the values you are using in your templates.

Comment: I mean  to ( <br> and <pre> ).I will try with pure HTML table.

Comment: This doesn't seem to help in a Azure DevOps dashboard markdown panel.  Any idea for there?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski, as the quoted documentation says, this feature "works within a wiki but not elsewhere".